# Click programmatically on an element in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I'm trying to perform a click on an element inside a website.
The website is loaded in a WebView (Android) and the click I'm trying to perform is made using JS code.
The problem is I'm getting:

"uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'click' of null"

The code I'm using in my WebViewClient class is:

```
view?.loadUrl("javascript:(function doSomething() { document.getElementById('id').click(); }) ()")
```

*I tried executing this line after a timer and after the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:(function doSomething() { document.getElementById('id').click(); }) ()", null);
```